# Accessing handlebars variable inside client js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm generating a handlebars view with hbs for express js framework, and I need to access the variables I pass to the view from inside a separate JavaScript file.

For example:

```
 var foo = {{user.name}}
```

Obviously this code throws an error, but what is the preferred way of getting hbs variables inside JavaScript?

Currently I'm running another ajax request to get the same data. but I think it is not wise to make another request for the same data...

Comment: I've edited your question with updates to the grammar and capitalization of words (especially I, which should be capitalized in the Engliish language). I'm afraid I know very little about handlebars or express, so I can't answer the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution, seems like i just had to put the handlebars variable inside a string for it to work.

In order to pass and Object to a variable I created hbs helper:

```
 hbs.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
 });
```

and the in my view:

```
 var currentUser = JSON.parse('{{{json user}}}');
```

and now i can access the data on the client side js.