# How to access local variables from res.render from client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using node.js express 4 
at my `index.js` routes file I have this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {items: myItemsdocs});
}};
```

at my `index.hbs` view I'm trying to use items as a javascript variable

```
var jsItems = items;
var name1 = jsItems[Object.keys(jsItems)[0]].itemName;
alert(name1);
```

but nothing happens .. how can I use items object I have in the client side javascript ?

my template engine is express-handlebars

Comment: `var jsItems = {{items}};`

Comment: @chrisG I tried it , doesn't work too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174185/accessing-handlebars-variable-inside-client-js-file

Comment: My example will only work for numbers; if you have a string, you need `var jsItems = "{{items}}";` If it's an array or anything like that, you need to serialize it, then parse it back into an object.

Answer (score 0):

From the client side you can load them to an array, and the client side can take the that array like below:

```
// in server side 
var dizi = [true,result._id]; res.send(dizi);

// and the client side (in js file)
var dizi  = response.data;
var mantiksal = dizi[0];
var _id = dizi[1];
```