# Is it possible to access a Handlebar variable through an external .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I hope all is well despite the pandemic we are experiencing right now. I am currently doing a school project and found myself stuck in an endless loop trying to figure things out. I am looking for a way how to access the data passed by my route handler to my handlebar template to my separate javascript file.

Please see attached code below:

**index.js (the route handler which passes the variables to my handlebar template)**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.loggedin){
        professorModel.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 3 } }]).then(function(qvProfs) {
            reviewModel.find({}).populate('profRef').populate('studentRef').sort({_id:-1}).limit(10).exec(function(err,mostRecent) {
                collegeModel.find({}).exec(function(err, col){
                    var colleges = [];
                    var reviews = [];

                    col.forEach(function(document){
                        colleges.push(document.toObject());
                    });

                    mostRecent.forEach(function(document){
                        reviews.push(document.toObject());
                    });

                    res.render('frontend/home',{
                        studentRef: req.session.studentRef,
                        idNum: req.session.idNum,
                        colleges: colleges,
                        data: qvProfs,
                        review: reviews,
                        title: 'Home',
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/login')
    };
});
```

**Main layout (the layout being used by 'frontend/home')**

```
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

**script.js (the external .js file to manipulate the html)**

```
    var newReview = {
      profName: $('#revProfName').find(":selected").text(),
      profCourse: $('#revProfCourse').find(":selected").text(),
      studentRef: "{{req.session.studentRef}}",
      studentId: "{{req.session.idNum}}",
      reviewContent: $("textarea#revContent").val()
    };
```

Everytime I do a console.log(newReview), I always get {{req.session.studentRef}} and {{req.session.idNum}} and not the actual value. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so looks like there is no direct way to get it working as the handlebar does not interpret the separate js files but here's a hack around.

1st you will need to pass the data window scope inside the view file.
to do that first register a helper function if you are passing json/javascript object data.

more info regarding this can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174185/accessing-handlebars-variable-inside-client-js-file)

```js
hbs.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

2nd step: Inside your view file add the data to the window scope.

```js
// if both variables you are sending are objects
window.studentRef = JSON.parse('{{{json studentRef}}}');
window.studentId = JSON.parse('{{{json studentRef}}}');
// if the variables you are sending are int or string
window.studentRef = {{studentRef}};
window.studentId = "{{studentRef}}";
```

Then you can access these from windows scope inside your js file on window load listener.

```js
// inside your js file
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    var newReview = {
      profName: $('#revProfName').find(":selected").text(),
      profCourse: $('#revProfCourse').find(":selected").text(),
      studentRef: window.studentRef,
      studentId: window.studentId,
      reviewContent: $("textarea#revContent").val()
    };
})
```

hope you got the idea of achieving it.

Comment: Hi Anees! Thank you so much for the solution! I was able to pull the data through and it's working properly! The studentId is actually an integer value and when I tried doing this: `window.studentId = {{studentRef}};` it gave me an undefined value; however, I was able to retrieve the data by wrapping it with quotes hence it converts the int as a string value. Is there any workaround for this one?

Comment: you can use function `parseInt` ... `window.studentid = parseInt("{{studentRef}}")`,

Comment: and if the answer solved your problem consider marking it as solution.

Comment: Hi Aneez! Would you happen to know how I could retrieve a boolean value? It just returns an empty character. thanks!

Comment: now idea of your problem.. between post a question and you will get a solution if your question is useful.